# How to edit header in feign response Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson, spring-cloud-feign

My feign client give respone a plain/text. How to change to application/java?
I can't turn json response into pojo. I think this is because the API returns JSON with Content-type: plain/text instead of application/json. How do I change the response header to application/json instead of plaint/text?

client.feign

```
@FeignClient(value = "${app.api.name}", url = "${app.api.url}")
public interface MozambiqueheApi {

    @GetMapping("/bridge?" + "auth=" + "${app.api.token}" + "&player={playerName}" + "&platform={playerPlatform}")
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    ResponseEntity<TestPojo> getInfoByPlayer(@PathVariable String playerName, @PathVariable Platforms playerPlatform);
```

controller.maincontroller

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

    private Feign feign;

    public MainController() {
        this.feign= Feign.builder()
                .requestInterceptor(new HeaderTestRequestInterceptor())
                .encoder(new JacksonEncoder())
                .decoder(new JacksonDecoder())
                .contract(new SpringMvcContract())
                .target(Feign.class, "https://api.test.re");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public ResponseEntity<TestPojo> getMain() {
        return feign.getInfoByPlayer("name", Platforms.PC);
    }
}
```

modifier.headertestrequestinterceptor

```
public class HeaderTestRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        requestTemplate.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
}
```

Json response from API

```
{
    "global": {
        "name": "name",
        "uid": 1234546897956,
        "avatar": "",
        "platform": "PC",
        "level": 23,
        "toNextLevelPercent": 62,
        "internalUpdateCount": 22,
        "bans": {
            "isActive": false,
            "remainingSeconds": 0,
            "last_banReason": "NONE"
        }
    }
}
```

model.testpojo

```
public class TestPojo {

    public static class Global {
        private String name;

        public Global() {
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    private Global global;

    public TestPojo() {
    }

    public Global getGlobal() {
        return global;
    }

    public void setGlobal(Global global) {
        this.global = global;
    }
}
```